# Spock mocked method doesn't return correct values

Tags: mocking, spock

Given a class Foo

```
Foo {
    boolean bar() {}
}
```

Why is it that when I use Spock to mock Foo

```
Foo fooInstance = Mock(Foo)
fooInstance.bar() >>> [true, true, true]
```

calling `fooInstance.bar()` always returns false?

Not sure if it makes a difference, but the test is in Groovy/Spock, and Foo is in Java 8.

Comment: Could you please provide the whole specification?

Comment: Your sample code for `Foo` is not a `class` unless you just forgot to add that here.

Comment: Why did you try to mock the return value to an array with thee booleans?
I guess this is what you want:

class Foo{
     boolean bar() {
      }
 }

   void "test foo"(){
       Foo fooInstance = Mock(Foo)
      fooInstance.bar() >> true;

      expect: fooInstance.bar()
  }

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected for me, here's the code (I had to fix your Foo class so it would compile by throwing a RuntimeException - but you never see this when the test runs):

```
/* In Groovy 2.4 */
import spock.lang.Specification

class FooTests extends Specification {

    def "test that bar always returns true"(){
        given: "a mock Foo"
        def mockFoo = Mock(Foo)
        mockFoo.bar() >>> [true, true, true]

        when: "we call bar 3 times"
        def result1 = mockFoo.bar()
        def result2 = mockFoo.bar()
        def result3 = mockFoo.bar()

        then: "the result should always be true"
        result1 == true
        result2 == true
        result3 == true
    }
}

/* In Java 8: */
class Foo {
    boolean bar() {
        throw new RuntimeException("should not happen");
    }
}
```

Change any of the three fixed return values to false and the test fails. Hope that helps!